# The attachfile2 package doesn't work when using \jobname

Tags: errors, miktex, texstudio, jobname, attachfile

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 on a Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit computer.

I have been experimenting with using `attachfile2` to make a link to an embedded LaTeX file. When I compile the following document, named `test.tex`,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myred}{rgb}{0.9,0.2,0.2}
\usepackage{attachfile2}
\attachfilesetup{color = myred}
\begin{document}
\jobname.tex \textattachfile{test.tex}{view source code}
\end{document}
```

it works as expected, producing the name of the file and a link:

[image]

But when I replace `test.tex` with `\jobname.tex` in the `\textattachfile` command, I get the following error (I am using TeXstudio 2.6.2):

[image]

Even putting `\expandafter` right before `\textattachfile`, which as far as I understand should ensure that `\textattachfile` never even sees the command `\jobname`, doesn't help.

What's going on?

---

Further observations (not sure if relevant):

- When I use `attachfile` instead of `attachfile2`, it works fine with the `\jobname` input (of course, the only difference being that I can't use my custom color, which is the reason I wanted to use `attachfile2` in the first place).
- As I mentioned, I'm using TeXstudio. This editor has a convenient feature where it (at least attempts to) detect the commands that are defined by any included packages, and then highlights any commands it doesn't recognize. When I use the `attachfile` package, the commands `\attachfilesetup` and `\textattachfile` are recognized; when I use the `attachfile2` package, they are not recognized. Perhaps my copy of the `attachfile2` package is broken somehow? MiKTeX tells me that I have the `oberdiek` bundle installed, which is apparently where `attachfile2` lives.
- I also tried using the `currfile` package, which provides a macro `\currfilename`. Nothing different happens when I replace `\jobname.tex` with `\currfilename`; it works and doesn't work in the same cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `attachfile` had read the backslash in the argument of `\textattachfile` with verbatim catcode before version 2011/03/27 v1.5b. Package `attachfile2` was written in that time before and has followed `attachfile` in this.

Now (2011/03/27 v1.5b) package `attachfile` reads the backslash with the usual catcode in `\textattachfile` to support `\jobname` (and other macros).

I have updated `attachfile2` accordingly: 2013/07/29 v2.10. The package is available [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71873949/tex/attachfile2-2.10.pdf) until I release my updated bundle to CTAN later (this year hopefully). The source file `attachfile2.dtx` is embedded as file attachment. The package file `attachfile2.sty` with the driver files are unpacked by running plain TeX (or iniTeX) on `attachfile2.dtx`.