# How do I make an attached file display like a link's title (no icon) when using the attachfile2 package

Tags: attachfile

I want make a string in the text clickable. When I click it (the string is an attachfile name or another custom name),then it should download the attachfile.

attached file.How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer here:[enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125813/the-attachfile2-package-doesnt-work-when-using-jobname?rq=1)

Werner helped me correct many grammatical errors in my question,thank you very much :)